# Does the UK have the military capability to deny Russia air supremacy over Ukraine?

Tags: united-kingdom, russian-federation, armed-conflict, ukraine

Some Tory backbenchers have called for British military intervention in the Russian invasian of Ukraine ([source](https://www.theguardian.com/world/2022/feb/24/conservative-mps-urge-increase-uk-military-aid-ukraine-russia)). The specific proposal seems to be to deny Russia air supremacy (which Russia claims[1](https://www.theguardian.com/world/2022/feb/24/conservative-mps-urge-increase-uk-military-aid-ukraine-russia) to have attained). Ignoring the potential for further escalation, I am wondering whether this is remotely within the British military capability.

Just to clarify terminology: Air supremacy is a degree of air superiority wherein the opposing air force is incapable of effective interference. (Thanks for o.m. for digging up the phrasing). Denying air supremacy to Russia is a significantly lower standard than trying to attain air superiority for a hypothetical interventionist.

[1](https://www.theguardian.com/world/2022/feb/24/conservative-mps-urge-increase-uk-military-aid-ukraine-russia) It has turned out that Russia's claims of having attained air supremacy early in the invasion were exaggerated at the very least; with Ukraine apparently still capable of conducting anti-air defense and even air-to-ground assault on their own.

Comment: You're asking about air-to-air combat between Russia and the RAF over Ukraine? Whether the UK (alone?) would be able to hold their own against Russia? I suspect that would be way too speculative, both because precise military capabilities are classified and we've never seen that sort of fight in the real world. Heck, has there *ever* been a real conflict between 2 modern airforces for air supremacy?

Comment: Hey, could you put in that quote?  It's priceless fantasy and it's coming from someone senior to boot.

Comment: @divibisan Denying air supremacy to your opponent is a rather different thing from trying to gain it yourself, at least that's my understanding.

Comment: To be fair to Davis, he seems to have been referring to NATO as a whole providing air support, not just the UK. https://mobile.twitter.com/DavidDavisMP/status/1496790747525402629 Still a rather questionable idea of course.

Comment: If UK would intervene, which I doubt, then probably not alone. UK alone against Russia is not realistic.

Comment: As @CDJB notes, the premise of this question is incorrect. It's clear from the original tweet (which I've submitted to replace the secondary source in the text) that he means NATO, not the UK alone.

Comment: @StackerLee The Guardian article summarizes statements by a bunch of politicians. It is a much better source imho than any individual tweet.

Comment: The UK is in too weak of a position to do anything due to having a very limited nuclear arsenal. Only nations with hundreds of ICBMs are a real threat to Russia, which narrows the list down to China and the US. Power talks, everyone else walks.

Comment: @Arno the wording of the guardian article is probably the reason for the misunderstanding. It is (intentionally?) misleading; the publication is politically polar opposite to Davis.

Comment: A week later, it appears that the answers below, like pretty much everyone else in the world, greatly overestimated the strength of Russia's air-force. It appears that *Ukraine* has the military capability to deny Russia air-supremacy, at least for the time being.

Comment: Russia can not make WW2-style carpet bombing of Ukrainian cities. The Ukrainian air defense would shot them all. That is not air superiority. Currently, in important battles last time in Avdiivka, they are doing gliding bombings out of the reach of the Ukrainian air defense. Also the Ukrainian air defense is a target, both for planes and drones, but it is not enough. Having UK planes would make the Ukrainian air force stronger, but still not to the level where they can get air superiority. Looks in this war, the air defense is stronger as the planes.

Comment: ...similarly as that anti-tank weapons are stronger as the tanks. But these are temporary development. The next phase will be anti-missile active rocketry on the tanks and better stealth on the planes. After that, probably clouds of the drones will appear.

Answer (score 21):

As of couple of years ago, air supremacy used to be defined as "[t]hat degree of air superiority wherein the opposing air force is incapable of effective interference." So the UK would have to help Ukraine to *interfere effectively* with Russian operations. That is a very low standard.

I dare say that the UK could *interfere* with Russian operations. As you mentioned, this would be highly escalatory, and it *might* prompt Russian attacks on the airbases -- interfering with the ability to interfere.

Comment: It's not that I am disagreeing with anything here, but you are not really offering anything of substance.

Comment: @Arno, what I'm saying is that "supremacy" is the highest ranking in a list of terms, and denying full success is much easier than denying success. Just with a glance at the numbers, it would seem that the UK can deny supremacy.

Comment: The Ukrainian air force, without the UK help, can not effectively interfere. Yet the Russian side has not air superiority, because the Ukrainian surface-to-air rocketry is still strong.

Answer (score 11):

No.

Russia has a more powerful air force than the UK solo and their aircraft would be operating from nearby bases.

While the UK would not be operating anywhere near its bases.  Assuming it wanted to, and moved to nearby airstrips, say in Poland, that would take weeks.

And obviously this is not the swiftest of ideas when dealing with a nuclear power.  Habits of avoiding direct confrontation need to prevail, as they did from 1950 to 1990.

There's plenty NATO and the EU can do to hold Russia to account.  Foolish ideas like those of these backbenchers don't count.

About those numbers:

Eyeballing the Russian [fighter/multiroles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_active_Russian_military_aircraft), I see about 800 in that role.

Lot less eyeballing needed [with the UK](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_active_United_Kingdom_military_aircraft):  101 Typhoons and 23 F35s.

Comment: *as they did from 1950 to* 17th January 1991, [Desert Storm - The Air War, Day 1 - Animated](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zxRgfBXn6Mg) - the question is if they can do that to each other; blow up all the radar and SAM sites (*that's* the definition of air superiority) and then use that time to blow up all the tanks. Which I think the EU, Russia, and the US could all do to each other if they wanted to.

Comment: @Mazura that's not at all what this part of my answer is about.  What it is about is that the USSR and the USA took extensive steps to avoid their troops shooting at each other during the Cold War.  Ditto NATO/Warsaw Pact.  Steps that were taken for excellent reasons:  avoiding WW3.  Desert Storm has nothing to do with.

Comment: Denying air supremacy isn't a very high bar to clear.  The UK doesn't need to clear Ukrainian airspace of Russian aircraft to manage it, they just need sufficient fighter or anti-aircraft presence to contest control of that airspace.

Comment: @Mark Glad I ain't a RAF flyboy with you in charge of throwing my life away with 8 to 1 odds, no logistics on location.  And, oh, let's not forget:  a *really, really,* timid set of rules of engagement because this after all concerns 2 nuclear powers in direct combat.  Military types often think civs don't have a clue, but your grasp of the subtleties of *superiority vs supremacy* certainly shows them!

Comment: The UK is not a nuclear power as well?

Answer (score 2):

Russia has 4,163 various aircraft such as fighters, transports, and helicopters. Compared to the UK's 555 fixed-wing aircraft not counting helicopters no the UK cannot deny Russia Air supremacy.

link for reference:
https://tass.com/defense/1375695

Comment: Thanks for digging up the data. But I feel this is a start only - to actually answer the question would be what kind of aircraft pose a serious threat to which others, etc.

Comment: Also how much aircrafts of UK can actually reach Ukraine

Comment: @ARNO even with that info the Russians still win by numbers alone.

Comment: @NoOne they cant without stopping in Poland or Estonia, Latvia, etc. By then the Russians already know where they are

Comment: Just the numbers are not sufficient because a significant difference in technology levels can easily counter a numerical advantage. I don't know whether or by how much the UK forces are more modern but say 50 years difference in technology (much bigger than it is here) would be enough to counter an almost arbitrary numerical disadvantage.

Comment: Russia has slightly more territory to defend. I doubt they'd be willing to leave, say, their Chinese border entirely undefended. The practically available numbers aren't as lopsided as this answer would portray.

Comment: @ceejayoz China doesn't want Russia they want Taiwan